# Excel Formula for conditional subtotals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to subtotal this data at each of the `xxxx`. I know I can go to each cell, but we are trying to create a template because this is just a small sample of the data. Any ideas for a column formula that would work?

```
    2   6500
    2   6500
    2   6500
    2   6500    xxxx
    3   6500
    3   6500
    3   6500
    3   6500
    3   6500
    3   6500    xxxx
    4   6500    xxxx
    5   6500
    5   6500    xxxx
    6   6500
    6   6500
    6   6500
    6   6500
    6   6500
    6   6500
    6   6500
    6   6500
    6   6500
    6   6500     xxxx
```

Comment: Have you looked at using a pivot table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data are in the range A1:B23, this array formula should do the job:

```
  =IF(A1<>A2,SUM(IF(A1=A$1:A1,$B$1:$B1,0),0),"")
```

The formula work by first checking whether the current group value (in A1) is equal to the group value in the next cell in column A.

If not, then calculate a sum of column B for all the previous cells in A that match the group value for the current cell. Otherwise, return an empty string.

Since this is an array formula, you will need to use the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination to enter it.

Comment: That works great, except I do not want a running subtotal. Sorry, I should have clarified. I need a NEW subtotal for each element in column A.

Comment: Oops. Will amend my answer.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, but that amended answer does the same thing.

Comment: Here's what it looks like in row 10: `=IF(A10<>A11,SUM(IF(A10=A$1:A10,$B$1:$B10,0),0),"")`.  I forgot to explain that it's an array formula which you need to enter with the Control-Shift-Enter key combination (and then can copy down)!